# I do not understand why these two functions dont both work

Tags: c++

The first function will appropriately change the universal variable chosenWord, but the second will not affect guessedWord at all. I understand that the functions are just copying the values of the variables, but why does it work in the first but not the second? And, how do I make the second one work?

```
void lowerCase() //Convert inputted word to lowercase
{
    int x = 0;
    while(chosenWord[x])
    {
        chosenWord[x] = tolower(chosenWord[x]);
        x++;
    }
}
void setupGuessString() //Set guessed word to same length as chosen word and replace each letter with '_'
{
    int x = 0;
    while(chosenWord[x])
    {
        guessedWord[x] = '_';
        x++;
    }
}
```

as defined in another .cpp (for practice):

```
std::string chosenWord;
std::string guessedWord;
```

as declared in a .h (again, for practice):

```
extern std::string chosenWord;
extern std::string guessedWord;
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting a compilation error? Is your application crashing? Do you get a result that is different from the one you expected? If so, what is that difference?

Comment: Show more snippets, where are both arrays defined and how?

Comment: You probably meant `while(guessedWord[x])` btw, not `chosenWord` in the second function, causing your `while` to never be entered.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to set guessedWord to the same length as chosenWord at the same time as replacing all the characters with underscores.

Comment: Ah-ha! So they're not arrays at all! That changes things. Next time you ask a question, show how you've defined the data you're working with right away, don't make people ask about it.

Comment: @phonetagger Will do. Sorry for the confusion, I am trying to get my head around this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand guessedWord is an empty string `string guessedWord = "";` so to set it up you need to add `'_'` characters to guessedWord, not to set them equal to `'_'`. So your function will be:

```
void setupGuessString()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (chosenWord[x]))
    {
        guessedWord += '_';
    }
}
```

And I would strongly recommend not to use global variables, instead of them use the return statement, that is just a better practise. So your functions will be:

```
string lowerCase(string chosenWord)
{
int x = 0;
while(chosenWord[x])
{
        chosenWord[x] = tolower(chosenWord[x]);
        x++;
    }
    return chosenWord;
}

string setupGuessString(string chosenWord)
{
    int x = 0;
    string guessedWord = "";
    while (chosenWord[x]))
    {
        guessedWord += '_';
    }
    return guessedWord;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As for the global variables, I am tracking, I just need to make the code work and then I will work on getting rid of those. I am very new and trying to get my head around it all.

Comment: If it returns guessedWord, how would that return be accessed in other functions? Would it just have to be a parameter of the other function? e.g. anotherFunction(setupGuessString()); ?

Comment: This function is just like in math imagine that guessString is just variable like x that let's say is equal to 2 if you have function y = x * 2 your function would take 2 and return 4. This is the same thing instead of 2 you have "" empty string and instead of multiplying it by 2 you just add '_' characters and get it as a result. So if you want to use this result in another function you can do something like this: anotherFunction(setupGuessString(chosenWord)); So imagine that instead of setupGuessString(chosenWord) you have your guessedWord.

Comment: Also you can make guessedWord equal to setupGuessString(chosenWord):  guessedWord = setupGuessString(chosenWord); It will behave in the same way as the global variable did, but such code with return is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Is guessedWord of type character array ?
Is it global array ?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
char *chosenWord = "Hello W";
char guessedWord[10];
void setupGuessString() //Set guessed word to same length as chosen word and replace each letter with '_'
{
    int x = 0;
    while(chosenWord[x])
    {
        guessedWord[x] = '_';
        x++;
    }
     guessedWord[x] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
    setupGuessString();
    printf("%s   ;; %s",chosenWord, guessedWord);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I see.. :
Hello W    ;; _______   <--- this